# github. Is importing enough?

Tags: python, django

If I wanted to incorporate a password strength meter from this page https://github.com/aj-may/django-password-strength, do I need to copy the 'django_password_strength' folder and paste it into my project or will doing the 'pip install django-password-strength' and then 'from django_password_strength.widgets import PasswordStrengthInput, PasswordConfirmationInput' take care of it? Sorry I'm a noob. The instructions don't make this clear, and I've never done something like this from github. I spent half hour trying both ways and couldn't get it either way, so was wondering what the right path is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing `pip install django-password-strength` will install the package in your environment. In general, you do not require to copy the source from github. But since you need to use it in django forms, it is required to add `django-password-strength` in installed apps of project (as mentioned in the documentation). For adding in installed apps, look for `INSTALLED_APPS` variable in the settings.py file located at `/path/to/project/<project_name>/<project_name>/settings.py`

Comment: Okay thanks. I think the part that confused me was the line 'If you bundle your js you can use django_password_strength/js/zxcvbn.js or django_password_strength/js/zxcvbn-async.js and django_password_strength/js/password_strength.js instead'.

Comment: Since bundling is used for putting all javascript dependencies together. I think the statement means you can use `django_password_strength/js/zxcvbn.js` or `django_password_strength/js/zxcvbn-async.js` along with `django_password_strength/js/password_strength.js` file (this file is mandatory) for the package to work. Although not very much sure.